# How to display DbEntityValidationException errors on the view?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm performing some cross-property validation on my model and would like to know the best way to display those errors on the view. This is what I have:

CONTROLLER

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Update(User user)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            userManager.Update(user);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
        {
           //not sure what to do here. 
        }
    }

    return View(user);
}
```

BUSINESS LOGIC LAYER (UserManager.cs)

```
public User Update(User user)
{
    ...

    try
    {
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
    {
        // Retrieve the error messages as a list of strings.
        var errorMessages = ex.EntityValidationErrors
                .SelectMany(x => x.ValidationErrors)
                .Select(x => x.ErrorMessage);

        // Join the list to a single string.
        var fullErrorMessage = string.Join("; ", errorMessages);

        // Combine the original exception message with the new one.
        var exceptionMessage = string.Concat(ex.Message, " The validation errors are: ", fullErrorMessage);

        // Throw a new DbEntityValidationException with the improved exception message.
        throw new DbEntityValidationException(exceptionMessage, ex.EntityValidationErrors);
    }

    return user;
}
```

CONTEXT (UserContext.cs)

```
protected override System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationResult ValidateEntity(System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbEntityEntry entityEntry, IDictionary<object, object> items)
        {
            try
            {
                    if (Users.Any(u => u.Id == ((User)entityEntry.Entity).Id && u.Name == ((User)entityEntry.Entity).Name))
                        return new DbEntityValidationResult(entityEntry, new List<DbValidationError>{
                                                                            new DbValidationError( "Id && Name", "Id and Name combination already added earlier")
                                                                         });

                    return base.ValidateEntity(entityEntry, items);
            }
```

What I'm not sure of is, when the exception reaches the controller, how can I then return those model errors to the view? Is there an "MVC" way to do it, or do I just need to place the error in the ViewBag and display it on my own?

Comment: ModelState.AddModelError?

Comment: There is an example here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg193959#Fluent

Comment: umm idk if this is the correct solution, but it is along these lines: `ModelState.AddModelError(user.property, ex.message);`

Comment: Its a bit unclear why you would need to do this. If the properties of the model are decorated with the appropriate validation attributes, then if the model is invalid, you will never get that far because you return the view (because `ModelState.IsValid` returns false (and the appropriate error messages will be displayed adjacent each property assuming you have included `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` for each property in the view.

Comment: If you did want to do this, then its just `ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, ex.message); return View(user);` and the message will be displayed in the `@Html.ValidationSummary(true)` element

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid That what worked, thanks.

Comment: @StephenMuecke This is because I am doing some server side cross-property validation, so this validation happens after SaveChanges is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I proposed in the comments and to let others know that this question has been answered.

```
ModelState.AddModelError(user.property, ex.message);
```

That will give you the custom error messages to display in the view from the controller.